# Select colums in pandas multi index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I probably have a rather simple pandas question, but despite having tried multiple solutions posted on stackoverflow, I can't figure out how to do it properly.

I have pandas multi-index Dataframe with the following structure:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydhQ4.png)

now I want to select a subset of this dataframe based on the first column headers (HDx_DATE)

The columns which I want to show are stored in a list, so for example
`columns_show = ["HD1_DATE", "HD2_DATE"]`

After the filtering, the Dateframe should look like this:

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xSFs.png)

So it should only show the system values and entered Values for the columns in the list.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your support

Daniel

Comment: `I have pandas multi-index Dataframe` - what is `print (df.columns)` ? from sample data it is not MultiIndex

Comment: Maybe my example was not good enough. Both rows in the screenshot are column headers, each HDx-Date has a seperate column for system value and entered value. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: #[Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you for the warm welcome. I will take care of theese guidelines in the future.

I finally was able to solve my problem by the help of this post:

[multi column selection with pandas xs function is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521388/multi-column-selection-with-pandas-xs-function-is-failed)

This did the trick for me:

```
select = df_compare_filtered.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(columns_show)
df_compare_filtered.loc[:, select]
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
       A               B                 C
system | user   system | user     system | user
   1       2       3      8          3      5
```

lets suppose the list columns show is:

```
columns_show = ["A", "C"]
```

Then the resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
       A               C                  
system | user   system | user
   1       2        3      5
```